# Most performant way to update millions of records

Tags: sql, postgresql

Any performant way to do this: `UPDATE entries SET tags = array_append(tags, 2) WHERE id IN [millions_of_ids_here]`.

My table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE entries(
  id BIGINT PRIMARY,
  label VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL,
  tags INT[]
);
```

There are 250 millions rows in table `entries`. I have a CSV file containing a list of id's, so I need to add a tag only to thoose ids. Example:

File `2.csv`:

```
2356489520,
0899436814,
6471055422,
...
```

A single csv file can contain some millions of id's. In above example, I need to add `2` to `tags` of all entries of that file.

Most answers I saw assume that the id's are sequentially, which is not my case.

Comment: [COPY](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-copy.html) `CSV` file into a staging table, then use that table `UPDATE ... FROM staging_table WHERE id = staging_table.id`

Comment: @AdrianKlaver Not a bad idea.